# Django-CMS static placeholder not working in site with translations

Tags: python, django, translation, django-cms

I have a site with Django/Django-CMS that has 3 languages and I've got a static placeholder for the newsletter form. The problem is that I add the plugin to this placeholder in my `pt` page and then edit the content in the other pages (`en` and `es`) so the text is translated and publish my changes. The problem is that in edit mode the changes appear but in publish mode it always assumes the `pt` translation. In the other placeholders (not static) this doesn't happen. I can't have static placeholders with translations?

UPDATE:

Here's a print of my plugin ID from the `pt` page:

[image: <code>pt</code> ID of my plugin]

And here's the ID of the `en` page:

[image: <code>en</code>ID of my plugin]

My static placeholder is defined like this:

```
{% static_placeholder "subscribe" %}
```

And I have 3 languages defined:

```
LANGUAGES = [
    ('pt', gettext('pt')),
    ('en', gettext('en')),
    ('es', gettext('es')),
]

CMS_LANGUAGES = {
    ## Customize this
    'default': {
        'public': True,
        'hide_untranslated': False,
        'redirect_on_fallback': True,
    },
    1: [
        {
            'public': True,
            'code': 'pt',
            'hide_untranslated': False,
            'name': gettext('pt'),
            'redirect_on_fallback': True,
        },
        {
            'public': True,
            'code': 'en',
            'hide_untranslated': False,
            'name': gettext('en'),
            'redirect_on_fallback': True,
        },
        {
            'public': True,
            'code': 'es',
            'hide_untranslated': False,
            'name': gettext('es'),
            'redirect_on_fallback': True,
        },
    ],
}
```

Comment: Quick question - are you sure that the static placeholder is present in all of the translated versions?I.e. is there a specific plugin there?

Comment: Yes I have specific plugin in my translated versions and I can see it in edit mode but then I publish and I see in published mode it show me the `pt` version.

Comment: @petr they have different IDs (i'll put the prtscr in my question)

Comment: It's good practice to pass the current site with this tag; `{% static_placeholder "subscribe" site %}`

Comment: Do you have a cache setup? This happens to me all the time because of the cache. If I flush it, the static placeholder updates

Comment: @LauraCristinaManzurVillalob in my dev environment I set the cache `False` and the problem still happens :s

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is caused by https://github.com/divio/django-cms/issues/5760.

In the meantime, for each language, please try editing/saving the plugin and then publishing.

Saving the plugin will mark the static placeholder as dirty, this will allow you to publish it on that language. Once you publish then the static placeholder is marked as not dirty, so you'll need to do this for every language.

**Edit**

Try running the following in a shell:

```
spl = StaticPlaceholder.objects.get(code='subscribe')
spl.publish(None, 'pt', force=True)
spl.publish(None, 'en', force=True)
spl.publish(None, 'es', force=True)
```

Comment: I've tried that already and it doesn't work. I alter the text and save it in my `en` page, then I publish but the published page keeps showing me the `pt`version.

Comment: @patricia this is strange.. can you provide me with the Placeholder ID? As well as a list of all language codes configured? I'll update my answer with some next steps.

Comment: Edited my question.

Comment: Hello @patricia, I've updated my answer to include some commands which should fix this for you. If they do I'm really interested in figuring out how did this happen in the first place as I'm unable to reproduce it.

Comment: Hi, that solved my problem but only temporarily because right after I changed the plugin in one of the languages the change didn't take effect. So this is the path, but I need something to work every time a change is made. Is some configuration missing in my project or something?

Comment: I can replicate the issue easily enough (django-cms 3.4.1), but I can also reliably overcome it.

If a static placeholder on a published page is stubbornly showing the content from a different language, then opening the placeholder and saving it again and publishing the page once more will reliably cause it to be published correctly. This is a bug that needs to be fixed.

Comment: @DanieleProcida I did that and still didn't publish my changes.